# Navigation Issue when importing the Android source code into Intellij-IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-source

I followed the standard process of importing android source code into IDEA.

Like this:

https://wiki.lineageos.org/import-android-studio-howto.html

Why not navigate to Message.java but Message.class in jar?

Message.class location:

/home/sdb/android_source/source/aosp/external/robolectric/v3/runtime/android-all-4.2.2_r1.2-robolectric-0.jar!/android/os/Message.class

[image: Why not navigate to Message.java but Message.class in jar]

Anyone knows how to fix it?

I have successfully built the source code.

IDEA version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-202.7660.26, built on October 6, 2020
Licensed to *****
Subscription is active until January 22, 2021
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.34 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 4.15.0-123-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 4062M
Cores: 4
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin
Current Desktop: Unity
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this will happen in cases where in addition to code, you have the JAR's included in IntelliJ as sources.

To fix this you should:

- In **Project Structure**, remove all JARs from classpath for SDKs you have included. See [this](http://effie.io/opening-aosp-with-intellij-part-3/) blog post for guide
- For the specific module/JAR that you don't want opened ( because you'd rather have IntelliJ open the source for example ), you can mark it as **Excluded**.
  For example in the blog linked above you have this:

[image]

Go in that screen, and find the folder/module/JAR that you want to ignore, and mark it as **Excluded**.

When it's exluded, then IntelliJ won't use it for "Ctrl + click" navigation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the class not from the project itself but from the dependency.

To be able to navigate to the dependency source file instead of the .class file - this library jar dependency (`android-all-4.2.2_r1.2-robolectric-0.jar`) must have the **sources** jar in addition to .class jar and this jar must be added as source type to the [library configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setup-library-dialog.html) in IDE. This is the dependency from robotletic [project](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) - it is not the Andorid Studio sources. So the sources for this must be downloaded in addition to .class file from the [central maven repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robolectric/android-all/9-robolectric-4913185-2/).

Comment: Since Roboelectric is a library for testing the Android framework, the 'sources' the OP needs are the 'actual' android framework that is present in the tree :)  IntelliJ is just mistakenly choosing the roboelectric JAR instead of the actual code. So the correct behaviour is to just ignore the lib, and use the actual framework code.

Comment: Looks like this Jar is added in the module's dependencies list. IDE will navigate to whichever dependency that is located higher in the [module dependencies tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html) list.